# Search from file vs. search from sql ntext field

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating news portal site. this saves to many news.Every news has html data. i'm using SQL Server 2005. I have 2 choices.

1. Save news data to ntext field.
2. Save news data to html file and save file name to nvarchar field.

What is best way to good performance and quick search operation. If i choose second way, when i search from news, i'm repeat every file and search from each.

What is best?

You have another way?

**EDIT**

Maybe my news count increasing over than 100,000. Now count is 1000. But SQL Server database size is 60Mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nvarchar(max), not ntext for storage. Use fulltext search for searching. Use the FILESTREAM storage if the content are documents that have to be accessed by Win32 API.

- [Querying varbinary(max) and xml Columns (Full-Text Search)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142531.aspx)
- [Best Practices for Integrated Full Text Search](http://sqlcat.com/msdnmirror/archive/2008/11/05/best-practices-for-integrated-full-text-search-ifts-in-sql-2008.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Queries on Large Catalogs: Lessons Learned](http://sqlcat.com/whitepapers/archive/2007/11/21/sql-server-2005-full-text-queries-on-large-catalogs-lessons-learned.aspx)
- [Using FILESTREAM with Other SQL Server Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895334.aspx#FullText)